# Centralize identity table and relations all table with one table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have an idea about a structure in SQL and not understand its good or bad, please help me.

My application have many table by having similar columns (creatorUserId, creatingDate, type,...) and all of them (tables) have n-to-n relation with others and itself.

It seems that all tables are derived from a base table, which includes similar columns and one identity column. I called the base table `Content` and added table with 2 columns (ContentParent_Id, ContentRelated_Id) for relations of "Contents".

Id column in Content table is identity and all of other table have one-to-one relation by Content table.

Also, several tables have been added to manage the common properties of all tables, such as display order, delete status, verification status, visit count, etc.

[image: db diagram sample]
Questions:

1. Should I add one-to-one relation and table and `ContentTable` and is not this overload for SQL?
2. When I execute query that select Reading that related by the person, it's slower than from when add n2n relation with person and reading. Why?
3. When executing query with Entity Framework with this code and see result in SQL Server Profiler, this shows table with many column that not used. Why?

   ```
    DB.Set<T>()
      .Include(q => q.Content)
      .Include(q => q.Content.ContentOrder)
      .Include(q => q.Content.ContentDelete)
      .Where(q => q.Content.ContentDelete.isDelete != 1)
   ```
4. Please share any suggestions that will improve the performance of this structure

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like it would be painful to work with. Not sure why you have all these content tables. They all seem like they should just be columns in the content table. But then the content table seems to really be nothing more than 6 columns in the other tables. It seems to me like you are overthinking and over engineering this.

Comment: Reminds a bit of [Bad CarMa](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/?article=292) - ok, that was even worse, but your approach goes into a similar direction. Many concepts that works just fine in an OO language like C# will **not** be easily "translated" or "applied" to relational databases - those are just two **very different** worlds, and things from one don't necessarily (or most often) don't work well in the other. You should **optimize** your relational modelling skills - not try to dream up something like this....

Comment: @SeanLange thanks. its a snapshot of small area from my db.do you say i should combine yellow area table(in image) with ContentTable? its field(yellow area) often 90% is null and i decide to separate it until optimize ContentTable ,its about 10 table or field.Is there a difference or optimization?

Comment: when fill a row on table for example Reading ,app must fill row in Content by readingTypeId by same ID and other table havent that id, i want to say every Id include just one of table.every contents maybe related to another contents that i managed this in ContentRelationTable.i dont want create n2n relational table for each two table.what is your idea? thanks you and @marc_s

Comment: I agree with Sean - This kind of structure is only going to make your life harder. It's kinda hard to recommend a better structure because is structure makes so little sense in a relational database perspective (though I agree with Marc - it makes perfect sense in an object oriented environment) it's very hard to know what's what. The basic rule is that every distinct data entity should have it's own table. If your data entity contains all person, file, group, media, tag and reading, then they should all belong to a single table.

Comment: I think you may have started venturing down the path of premature optimization. That is making non-standard design decisions to deal with a performance problem that doesn't exist. It is pure evil, just design your tables following standard normalization practices.